# Xamarin Studio 6.1.3 add-in broken

Tags: xamarin-studio

I'm trying to add an addin to xamarin studio, I've change channel from time to time, and currently running Stable 6.1.3. But for some reason I'm not able to search any addins in the gallery. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually yes.
For some reason the 6.1.3 version of the repositories is bugged (I think).

If you go to your Add-in Manager / Gallery / Manage Repositorites

then add the following url http://addins.monodevelop.com/Stable/Mac/6.1.2/main.mrep (which is the same than the actual, but targeting 6.1.2), it should work. Worked for me at least.

Comment: Thanks, Fixes everything :)